# excel 2010 incrementing numbers in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to increment numbers using the "pull-down" method [?], but when I try to do this, it increases the first number (the "year") NOT the "day" figure.
e.g.,

```
1957 09 02
```

I want to pull & drag down this, so that the next cells down will read

```
1957 09 03
1957 09 04
1957 09 05
```

etc.
but, what I get is

```
1958 09 02
1959 09 02
1960 09 02
```

etc.

It doesn't seem to matter what the column is formatted as, text, number – I cannot get it to act as I wish.
ideas?

Comment: I imagine this is because you are using a space separator instead of a dot or slash. Try changing the format to "1957.09.02" and dragging that down.

Comment: you know, that works - and i can "replace" the decimal points with spaces after,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using a `space` as a `separator` in your `date` format. Replace the `space` with a `dot` and you will be able to drag the `date` down as expected.